# Outlook rule to identify emails sent to person A and B (instead of A or B)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, forwarding, email-filter, rules

Outlook rules allow exception for emails addressed to either of listed names. What if I want to handle emails sent specifically to person A and person B and potentially someone else?

This could be probably done through group containing A and B and then defined as recipient. Is there way to avoid groups?

Comment: You may have a look at this article which provided a detailed description of thims's method: https://www.msoutlook.info/question/220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. In order to achieve such *"AND"* behaviour in Outlook rules, you need to create two rules:

1. Condition: *"sent to A"*; Action: *"assign it to the category"* (any category you like, say "Sent to A"), do **not** set check the *"stop processing more rules"* action.
2. Conditions: *"sent to B"* and *"assigned to the "Sent to A" category"*; Actions: any actions you need.

You have to place the first rule above the second in the list of Outlook rules.